# Why does an SMS containing a link via Twilio not work?

Tags: python, web, hyperlink, twilio, twilio-api

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = '[AccountSid]'
auth_token = '[AuthToken]'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
  from_='[TwilioNumber]',
  body='Test message https://chartwo.com',
  to='[MyNumber]'
)

print(message.sid)
```

No matter what I do, Twilio takes hours to send this SMS and some it doesn't even want to send. What is that ? How can I get around this error? Could there be a problem with the destination site in question?

Comment: I’m sorry you’re having technical difficulties. If you have issues with the delivery, this probably means there is something wrong in the backend (possibly with the carrier network). I’d recommend reaching out to [Twilio Support](https://help.twilio.com/) and to share the SID of the message.